# javascript array of objects get uniq values by specific key value

Tags: javascript

I have bar like:

[image]

Server returns:

```
const rows = [
 {type: "global", count: 6, name: "Name", orderliness: 1},
 {type: "global", count: 5, name: "Name", orderliness: 2},
 {type: "local", count: 1, name: "Name", orderliness: 3},
 {type: "global", count: 8, name: "Name", orderliness: 3},
 {type: "local", count: 2, name: "Name", orderliness: 1},
]
```

And I should get not repeated `orderliness` and get output:

```
[
 {type: "global", count: 5, name: "Name", orderliness: 2}
]
```

And `push` no repeated item to `rows` like:

```
const rows = [
 {type: "global", count: 6, name: "Name", orderliness: 1},
 {type: "global", count: 5, name: "Name", orderliness: 2},
 {type: "local", count: 1, name: "Name", orderliness: 3},
 {type: "global", count: 8, name: "Name", orderliness: 3},
 {type: "local", count: 2, name: "Name", orderliness: 1},
 // this item I pushed
 {type: "local", count: 0, name: "Name", orderliness: 2},
]
```

I tried do like:

```
function getUnique(arr, comp) {
    return (
        arr
            .map((e) => e[comp])
            // store the keys of the unique objects
            .map((e, i, final) => final.indexOf(e) === i && i)
            // eliminate the dead keys & store unique objects
            .filter((e) => arr[e])
            .map((e) => arr[e])
    );
}
getUnique(rows, 'orderliness');
```

But it returns like:

```
[
 {type: "global", count: 6, name: "Name", orderliness: 1},
 {type: "global", count: 5, name: "Name", orderliness: 2},
 {type: "local", count: 1, name: "Name", orderliness: 3},
]
```

Comment: Can you explain *why* the desired output is the correct output?  What is the logic being employed?  Without that, no one can help you with how to implement it.

Comment: ^^ also: what is `comp`? what is `arr`? They both seem to be important to the logic of the code you're provided.

Comment: @ScottHunter I added additional information

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I added additional information

Comment: *"And I should sort it by `orderliness` and get output"* Sorting doesn't filter. You're showing a filtered result (original is five rows, "output" immediately following that sentence is one row). Filtered on what? What makes the `orderliness: 2` entry special?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry. I edited. I should get not repeated object by `orderliness`. I should get not repeated value and should create other object. If it has `type: global` create with `type: local`. And If `type: local` create `type: global` and set `count: 0`

Comment: I get it now. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have an array with rows where entries are of one of two types (`"global"` and `"local"`), and you're trying to find rows that only have one type and not the other then, having found them, push new rows for for the "other" type into `rows` with `count` set to 0.

Here's how I'd do it (see comments).

For `getUnique`:

```
function getUnique(arr, comp) {
    // Get a count of matching objects
    const counts = new Map();
    for (const {[comp]: value} of arr) {
        const count = counts.get(value) || 0; // `get` returns `undefined` if it's
                                              // not there; we replace that with 0
        counts.set(value, count + 1);
    }
    // Return only the unique ones
    return arr.filter(({[comp]: value}) => counts.get(value) === 1);
}
```

That makes two passes through the array rather than four, taking advantage of Map's binary tree or similar sublinear lookup time.

Then to add the rows:

```
// Get the unique rows, create new rows for the "other"
// type with count = 0 and push them into `rows`
rows.push(...getUnique(rows, 'orderliness').map(entry => ({
    ...entry,
    type: entry.type === "global" ? "local" : "global",
    count: 0
})));
```

Live Example:

```js
function getUnique(arr, comp) {
    // Get a count of matching objects
    const counts = new Map();
    for (const {[comp]: value} of arr) {
        const count = counts.get(value) || 0; // `get` returns `undefined` if it's
                                              // not there; we replace that with 0
        counts.set(value, count + 1);
    }
    // Return only the unique ones
    return arr.filter(({[comp]: value}) => counts.get(value) === 1);
}

const rows = [
    {type: "global", count: 6, name: "Name", orderliness: 1},
    {type: "global", count: 5, name: "Name", orderliness: 2},
    {type: "local", count: 1, name: "Name", orderliness: 3},
    {type: "global", count: 8, name: "Name", orderliness: 3},
    {type: "local", count: 2, name: "Name", orderliness: 1},
];

// Get the unique rows, create new rows for the "other"
// type with count = 0 and push them into `rows`
rows.push(...getUnique(rows, 'orderliness').map(entry => ({
    ...entry,
    type: entry.type === "global" ? "local" : "global",
    count: 0
})));
console.log(rows);
```